# can't log in on battle.net

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I've installed Hearthstone in PlayOnLinux, the install was successful but when I open Hearthstone I get an error and can't even log in to battle.net

This is the error i get.

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x0000049c in 32-bit code (0x10b489bb).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:10b489bb ESP:0033d5bc EBP:0033d5c4 EFLAGS:00210246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:00000000 EBX:578666e0 ECX:268291c8 EDX:26f544a0
 ESI:0033d660 EDI:579189d8
Stack dump:
0x0033d5bc:  3182c000 0033d660 0033d5f0 10b48fc8
0x0033d5cc:  0033d660 3182c000 578666e0 26806e3c
0x0033d5dc:  00000001 578f6900 00000001 00000001
0x0033d5ec:  00000000 0033d818 10ab113c 0033d660
0x0033d5fc:  3182c000 578666e0 3182c000 00000000
0x0033d60c:  00000001 578f6900 00000001 00000001
Backtrace:
=>0 0x10b489bb in libcef (+0xb489bb) (0x0033d5c4)
  1 0x10b48fc8 in libcef (+0xb48fc7) (0x0033d5f0)
  2 0x10ab113c in libcef (+0xab113b) (0x0033d818)
  3 0x10ab577c in libcef (+0xab577b) (0x0033d864)
  4 0x10b555a5 in libcef (+0xb555a4) (0x0033d96c)
  5 0x10b55ca2 in libcef (+0xb55ca1) (0x0033da90)
  6 0x10aecb9e in libcef (+0xaecb9d) (0x0033e4b4)
  7 0x10aec945 in libcef (+0xaec944) (0x0033e62c)
  8 0x10aec59d in libcef (+0xaec59c) (0x0033e6bc)
  9 0x10adcbfe in libcef (+0xadcbfd) (0x0033e750)
  10 0x10adc045 in libcef (+0xadc044) (0x0033e774)
  11 0x10acc1b0 in libcef (+0xacc1af) (0x0033e78c)
  12 0x10adc3d9 in libcef (+0xadc3d8) (0x0033e7e0)
  13 0x10adc90b in libcef (+0xadc90a) (0x0033e814)
  14 0x10adcc0e in libcef (+0xadcc0d) (0x0033e8a8)
  15 0x10adc045 in libcef (+0xadc044) (0x0033e8cc)
  16 0x10acc1b0 in libcef (+0xacc1af) (0x0033e8e4)
  17 0x10adc3d9 in libcef (+0xadc3d8) (0x0033e938)
  18 0x10adc90b in libcef (+0xadc90a) (0x0033e96c)
  19 0x10adcc0e in libcef (+0xadcc0d) (0x0033ea00)
  20 0x10adc045 in libcef (+0xadc044) (0x0033ea24)
  21 0x10acc1b0 in libcef (+0xacc1af) (0x0033ea3c)
  22 0x10adc3d9 in libcef (+0xadc3d8) (0x0033ea90)
  23 0x10adc90b in libcef (+0xadc90a) (0x0033eac4)
  24 0x10adcc0e in libcef (+0xadcc0d) (0x0033eb58)
  25 0x10adc045 in libcef (+0xadc044) (0x0033eb7c)
  26 0x10acc1b0 in libcef (+0xacc1af) (0x0033eb94)
  27 0x10adc3d9 in libcef (+0xadc3d8) (0x0033ebe8)
  28 0x10adc90b in libcef (+0xadc90a) (0x0033ec1c)
  29 0x10adcc0e in libcef (+0xadcc0d) (0x0033ecb0)
  30 0x10adc045 in libcef (+0xadc044) (0x0033ecd4)
  31 0x10acc1b0 in libcef (+0xacc1af) (0x0033ecec)
  32 0x10a93824 in libcef (+0xa93823) (0x0033ed28)
  33 0x108612e6 in libcef (+0x8612e5) (0x0033ed7c)
  34 0x108605fc in libcef (+0x8605fb) (0x0033edf4)
  35 0x106aafc1 in libcef (+0x6aafc0) (0x0033ee0c)
  36 0x106ab072 in libcef (+0x6ab071) (0x0033ee20)
  37 0x1068e247 in libcef (+0x68e246) (0x0033ee40)
  38 0x10c4d502 in libcef (+0xc4d501) (0x0033ee4c)
  39 0x10c4a0d6 in libcef (+0xc4a0d5) (0x0033ee58)
  40 0x1050e67e in libcef (+0x50e67d) (0x0033ee84)
  41 0x103fe969 in libcef (+0x3fe968) (0x0033eee0)
  42 0x103fdfca in libcef (+0x3fdfc9) (0x0033ef10)
  43 0x105137e2 in libcef (+0x5137e1) (0x0033ef68)
  44 0x10513ba5 in libcef (+0x513ba4) (0x0033efd0)
  45 0x1c00ad56 (0x0033efec)
  46 0x2f4b05c1 (0x0033f01c)
  47 0x2f4a5b4d (0x0033f03c)
  48 0x1c02cdbe (0x0033f060)
  49 0x2f4a4659 (0x0033f084)
  50 0x1c00b03b (0x0033f0a0)
  51 0x1c04ca50 (0x0033f0c8)
  52 0x2f4a4368 (0x0033f100)
  53 0x1c00b03b (0x0033f118)
  54 0x1c04ca50 (0x0033f140)
  55 0x2f4a3e0a (0x0033f184)
  56 0x2f4a212a (0x0033f1a8)
  57 0x1c00b03b (0x0033f1c4)
  58 0x1c04ca50 (0x0033f1ec)
  59 0x2f4a1360 (0x0033f21c)
  60 0x2f4a09db (0x0033f234)
  61 0x2f4a07f6 (0x0033f250)
  62 0x2f49dee7 (0x0033f2b4)
  63 0x1c00b03b (0x0033f2cc)
  64 0x2f49e006 (0x0033f2ec)
  65 0x1c04a7b5 (0x0033f308)
  66 0x1c01a76a (0x0033f344)
  67 0x1041d8cd in libcef (+0x41d8cc) (0x0033f388)
  68 0x1041cb2c in libcef (+0x41cb2b) (0x0033f3bc)
  69 0x103e5146 in libcef (+0x3e5145) (0x0033f408)
  70 0x10d9a7ba in libcef (+0xd9a7b9) (0x0033f458)
  71 0x10bdc8d9 in libcef (+0xbdc8d8) (0x0033f4d8)
  72 0x10bdc575 in libcef (+0xbdc574) (0x0033f530)
  73 0x10bdcdfa in libcef (+0xbdcdf9) (0x0033f55c)
  74 0x106f00f0 in libcef (+0x6f00ef) (0x0033f5c0)
  75 0x106efdd0 in libcef (+0x6efdcf) (0x0033f640)
  76 0x106e32b5 in libcef (+0x6e32b4) (0x0033f67c)
  77 0x11789c0b in libcef (+0x1789c0a) (0x0033f6e4)
  78 0x11651ed7 in libcef (+0x1651ed6) (0x0033f710)
  79 0x10141c67 in libcef (+0x141c66) (0x0033f730)
  80 0x1014d141 in libcef (+0x14d140) (0x0033f7d8)
  81 0x10124df8 in libcef (+0x124df7) (0x0033f8c8)
  82 0x10124606 in libcef (+0x124605) (0x0033f960)
  83 0x1014ea97 in libcef (+0x14ea96) (0x0033f984)
  84 0x10124bb0 in libcef (+0x124baf) (0x0033f9b4)
  85 0x10124b66 in libcef (+0x124b65) (0x0033f9d8)
  86 0x11c40ebc in libcef (+0x1c40ebb) (0x0033fc50)
  87 0x114e4bee in libcef (+0x14e4bed) (0x0033fc70)
  88 0x114e4aa6 in libcef (+0x14e4aa5) (0x0033fcd0)
  89 0x114e3de3 in libcef (+0x14e3de2) (0x0033fce0)
  90 0x10078eec in libcef (+0x78eeb) (0x0033fda4)
  91 0x10046fcd in libcef (+0x46fcc) (0x0033fdc8)
  92 0x0048dd35 in battle.net helper (+0x8dd34) (0x0033fdec)
  93 0x00401ee8 in battle.net helper (+0x1ee7) (0x0033fe14)
  94 0x004a2a59 in battle.net helper (+0xa2a58) (0x0033fe60)
  95 0x7b466aec call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0033fe78)
  96 0x7b467d1b in kernel32 (+0x47d1a) (0x0033feb8)
  97 0x7bc84540 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0033fed8)
  98 0x7bc876ad call_thread_func+0x7c() in ntdll (0x0033ffa8)
  99 0x7bc8451e RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0033ffc8)
  100 0x7bc559de call_dll_entry_point+0x35d() in ntdll (0x0033ffe8)
  101 0xf755acbd wine_call_on_stack+0x1c() in libwine.so.1 (0x00000000)
  102 0xf755ad7b wine_switch_to_stack+0x2a() in libwine.so.1 (0xffe8a308)
  103 0x7bc5be21 LdrInitializeThunk+0x270() in ntdll (0xffe8a358)
  104 0x7b46e428 __wine_kernel_init+0x987() in kernel32 (0xffe8b278)
  105 0x7bc5cd53 __wine_process_init+0x182() in ntdll (0xffe8b308)
  106 0xf75590a2 wine_init+0x2a1() in libwine.so.1 (0xffe8b368)
  107 0x7c000beb main+0x7a() in <wine-loader> (0xffe8b7a8)
  108 0xf7379637 __libc_start_main+0xf6() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x10b489bb: movl    0x49c(%eax),%ecx
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (166 modules)
PE    340000-  3ad000   Deferred        msvcp140
PE    400000-  56a000   Export          battle.net helper
PE   1d20000- 1ec5000   Deferred        ffmpegsumo
PE  10000000-12408000   Export          libcef
ELF 7b400000-7b7e9000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b420000-7b7e9000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcf7000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcf7000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c003000   Dwarf           <wine-loader>
ELF 7cb60000-7cb75000   Deferred        gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
ELF 7cb75000-7cbac000   Deferred        p11-kit-trust.so
ELF 7cbac000-7cc31000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7cc31000-7ccfa000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7ccfa000-7cd32000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7cd00000-7cd32000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7cd32000-7cd39000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7cd39000-7cd44000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7cd44000-7cd57000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7cd57000-7cd5b000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7cd5b000-7cd68000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7cd68000-7cd74000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7cd74000-7cd7b000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7cd7b000-7cd7f000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7cd7f000-7cd86000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7cd86000-7cd8a000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7cd8a000-7cdb0000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7cdb0000-7cefb000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7cefb000-7cf10000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7cf10000-7cfa5000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7cf20000-7cfa5000   \               winex11
ELF 7cfa5000-7cfbb000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7cfbb000-7d030000   Deferred        libpcre.so.3
ELF 7d030000-7d04d000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7d04d000-7d0fc000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 7d0fc000-7d122000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7d122000-7d148000   Deferred        libselinux.so.1
ELF 7d148000-7d1d6000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 7d1d6000-7d1df000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7d1df000-7d1e4000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7d1e4000-7d23e000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d23e000-7d2ca000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 7d2ca000-7d2ff000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7d2ff000-7d33b000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7d33b000-7d350000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d350000-7d384000   Deferred        libidn.so.11
ELF 7d384000-7d3e5000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d3e5000-7d3f2000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d3f2000-7d3f7000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7d3f7000-7d428000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d428000-7d4ff000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d4ff000-7d513000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7d513000-7d521000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7d521000-7d679000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7d679000-7d6cb000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d6cb000-7d752000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7d75b000-7d76d000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
ELF 7d8a4000-7d8ce000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7d8ce000-7d917000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7d917000-7d942000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7d942000-7d9f2000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7da0f000-7da22000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0<el
PE  7da10000-7da22000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0
PE  7da22000-7da35000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-
PE  7da30000-7da35000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
PE  7da35000-7da48000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0
PE  7da40000-7da48000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
ELF 7da48000-7da5b000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7da50000-7da5b000   \               api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0
ELF 7da5b000-7da70000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0<el
PE  7da60000-7da70000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0
ELF 7da70000-7da86000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0<
PE  7da80000-7da86000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0
ELF 7da86000-7db74000   Deferred        ucrtbase<elf>
  \-PE  7daa0000-7db74000   \               ucrtbase
ELF 7dba6000-7dbbf000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7dbb0000-7dbbf000   \               api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0
ELF 7dbbf000-7dbd4000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7dbc0000-7dbd4000   \               api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0
ELF 7dbd4000-7dbe9000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0<el
PE  7dbe0000-7dbe9000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0
ELF 7dbe9000-7dbfc000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0<elf
PE  7dbf0000-7dbfc000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0
ELF 7dbfc000-7dc0f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  7dc00000-7dc0f000   \               api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0
ELF 7dc0f000-7dc24000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0<elf
PE  7dc10000-7dc24000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0
ELF 7dc24000-7dc95000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  7dc30000-7dc95000   \               setupapi
ELF 7dc95000-7dcda000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7dca0000-7dcda000   \               usp10
ELF 7dcda000-7ddab000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7dce0000-7ddab000   \               crypt32
ELF 7ddab000-7ddc4000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7ddcc000-7dde1000   Deferred        vcruntime140<elf>
  \-PE  7ddd0000-7dde1000   \               vcruntime140
ELF 7dde1000-7de09000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ddf0000-7de09000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7de09000-7de38000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7de10000-7de38000   \               netapi32
ELF 7de38000-7de6c000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7de40000-7de6c000   \               secur32
ELF 7de6c000-7decb000   Deferred        oleacc<elf>
  \-PE  7de70000-7decb000   \               oleacc
ELF 7decb000-7def0000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7ded0000-7def0000   \               imm32
ELF 7def0000-7df1a000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7df00000-7df1a000   \               msacm32
ELF 7df1a000-7dfd4000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7df20000-7dfd4000   \               winmm
ELF 7dfd4000-7dfeb000   Deferred        wtsapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7dfe0000-7dfeb000   \               wtsapi32
ELF 7dfeb000-7dfff000   Deferred        dhcpcsvc<elf>
  \-PE  7dff0000-7dfff000   \               dhcpcsvc
ELF 7dfff000-7e03a000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e010000-7e03a000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e03a000-7e061000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7e040000-7e061000   \               mpr
ELF 7e061000-7e07a000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e07a000-7e0f7000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7e080000-7e0f7000   \               wininet
ELF 7e0f7000-7e19b000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7e100000-7e19b000   \               urlmon
ELF 7e19b000-7e1b3000   Deferred        userenv<elf>
  \-PE  7e1a0000-7e1b3000   \               userenv
ELF 7e1b3000-7e1d0000   Deferred        jsproxy<elf>
  \-PE  7e1c0000-7e1d0000   \               jsproxy
ELF 7e1d0000-7e20f000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  7e1e0000-7e20f000   \               winhttp
ELF 7e20f000-7e355000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e230000-7e355000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e355000-7e3db000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e360000-7e3db000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e3db000-7e522000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e3f0000-7e522000   \               ole32
ELF 7e522000-7e62e000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e530000-7e62e000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e62e000-7e87c000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e640000-7e87c000   \               shell32
ELF 7e87c000-7e96c000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7e880000-7e96c000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7e96c000-7e9ae000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7e970000-7e9ae000   \               winspool
ELF 7e9ae000-7e9c7000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7e9b0000-7e9c7000   \               version
ELF 7e9c7000-7ea43000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9e0000-7ea43000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ea43000-7eb79000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea50000-7eb79000   \               gdi32
ELF 7eb79000-7ecd8000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb90000-7ecd8000   \               user32
ELF 7ecd8000-7ed53000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ecf0000-7ed53000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7ed53000-7ed66000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed66000-7ed73000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ed73000-7ed8e000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef8e000-7efe3000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efed000-7f000000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               psapi
ELF f7351000-f735b000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f735c000-f7361000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7361000-f7517000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7517000-f7534000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7537000-f7540000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF f7552000-f7709000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f770b000-f7730000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f7732000-f7733000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    000000b7    0
    0000001f    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001e    0
    00000019    0
    00000018    0
    00000013    0
0000001c plugplay.exe
    00000022    0
    00000021    0
    0000001d    0
0000002a explorer.exe
    0000002e    0
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
00000037 Agent.exe
    0000004b    0
    0000004a    0
    00000049    0
    00000048    0
    00000047    0
    00000046    0
    00000045    0
    00000044    0
    00000043    0
    00000042    0
    00000040    0
    0000003c    0
    00000038    0
0000003a wineconsole.exe
    0000003b    0
00000052 Battle.net.exe
    00000112    0
    00000111    0
    00000109    0
    00000102    0
    000000ff    0
    000000fc    0
    000000fb    0
    000000f7    0
    000000f6    0
    000000f5    0
    000000f3    0
    000000ee    0
    000000ed    0
    000000ec    0
    000000eb    0
    000000ea    0
    000000e9    0
    000000e8    0
    000000e7    0
    000000e6    0
    000000e5    0
    000000e4    0
    000000e3    0
    000000e2    0
    000000e1    0
    000000e0    0
    000000df    0
    000000de    0
    000000dd    0
    000000dc    0
    000000db    0
    000000da    0
    000000d9    0
    000000d8   15
    000000d7    0
    000000d6    0
    000000d5    0
    000000d4    0
    000000d3    0
    000000d2    0
    000000cb    0
    000000c7    0
    000000c6   15
    000000c5    0
    000000c4    0
    000000c3    0
    000000c2    0
    000000c1    0
    000000c0    0
    000000b1    0
    000000ac    0
    000000aa    0
    000000a9    0
    0000009a    0
    00000063    0
    00000053    0
00000100 (D) C:\Program Files\Battle.net\Battle.net.8265\Battle.net Helper.exe
    00000110    0
    0000010e    0
    0000010d    0
    0000010c    0
    0000010b    0
    0000010a    0
    00000108    0
    00000107    0
    00000106    0
    00000105    0
    00000101    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.9.18
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows XP
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.4.0-59-generic
```

Graphics card: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`

Comment: What graphics card and drivers?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Comment: In the future please edit your question when adding new data. Don't let it only in comments.

Comment: Also read this: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30038 <- Most likely there's no solution for your issue.